# Determining if users are facebook friends (Parsing)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-4, koala-gem, facebook-friends

I'd like to find out if the current user is friends with the root node user, using Koala, and if so, print a statement saying: you are friends.
My problem is the parsing of data returned from facebook.

user.rb

```
def facebook
  @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
  block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e
  logger.info e.to_s
  nil # or consider a custom null object
end

def facebook_friend
  facebook.get_connection("me", "friends/#user.user_id")
end
```

Profile.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.facebook_friend.include?(@user.uid)? %>
  <p> you are friends</p>               
<% else %>
  <p> you are not friends</p>   
<% end %>
```

Output:

```
<%= current_user.facebook_friend %>
```

will return: [{"name"=>"Elizabeth", "id"=>"100008217009369"}]

```
<%= @user.uid %>
```

will return: 100008217009369

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It was much easier than I thought:
In the user model simple used the Koala method:

```
def facebook_friend(user)
  facebook.get_connection("me", "friends/#{user.uid}")
end

def my_friends_list
  facebook.get_connection("me", "friends")
end
```

Then in the Profile View, adding current_user and @user as arguments:

```
<% if @user.uid.present? %>
  <% if signed_in? && current_user == @user %>
    <p><%= current_user.my_friends_list.count %> friends</p>
  <% elsif current_user.facebook_friend(@user).empty? %>
    <p><%= current_user.mutual_friends.count %> friends in common</p>
  <% else %>
    <p>You are Facebook friends</p>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p>Not connected</p>
<% end %>
```